# How to properly initialize a const int const * variable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization, constants

So I have a `struct`:

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    const int *const array_ptr;
} myStruct_s;
```

I have a `const` array of `int`:

```
const int constArray[SIZE1] =
{
        [0] = 0,
        [1] = 1,
        [2] = 2,
        //...
};
```

Now I have a `const` array of `myStruct_s` initialized with designated intializers:

```
const myStruct_s structArray[SIZE2] =
{
        [0] =
            {
                    .array_ptr = &constArray
            },
        //...
}
```

I get the warning:

> a value of type "const int (*)[SIZE1]" cannot be used to initialize an
>   entity of type "const int *const"

How can I properly initialize this pointer?

I'd like to avoid:

```
const myStruct_s structArray[SIZE2] =
{
        [0] =
            {
                    .array_ptr = (const int *const) &constArray
            },
        //...
}
```

If possible, since I feel like I tell the compiler *"I don't know what I am doing, just don't check the type please"...*

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: `array_ptr = &constArray[0];`

Comment: Array indexes start at 0. Your assignments (`[1] = 1`) start at 1. Not related to the problem, but looks suspicious.

Comment: @davmac: You are right! Actually I use `enum` as indexes to fill the arrays. I never use magic numbers :). I simplified my code a bit too quickly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`constArray` is already (decays into) a pointer, you want

```
.array_ptr = constArray
```

or

```
.array_ptr = &constArray[0] /* pointer to the first element */
```

instead of

```
.array_ptr = &constArray /* you don't want the address of */
```

Consider

```
int a[] = {1,2};
int *p = &a;
```

This is not correct because `p` wants a pointer to an `int` (`&a[0]` or simply `a`), not a pointer to an array of 2 `int` (`&a`)

Comment: Correct, but could use an explanation of exactly why `&constArray` doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, ok, I will try but my english is very poor :)

Comment: @Plouff: you are welcome, you can find more details at [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 6.13](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html)

Comment: @AlterMann: Thanks again for the C FAQ link :).